# how to create sections of grouped data in Vf page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a List with data below

```
customer name  Make      Area
Mike           honda     Chicago
Kevin          GM        Chicago
Bill           Audi      New York
roger          Suzuki    New York
```

i need to display this info in Vf page with the Area as sections and name and make under it

```
New york
Roger          Suzuki    
Bill           Audi      

Chicago
Mike           honda     
Kevin          GM
```

Any pointers on how to get this would be of great help.

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two potential ways to do this, the first (which definitely works) would be to use a wrapper class in you controller like so:

```
public class CArea
{
    public list<Contact> liContacts {get; set;}
    public string strAreaName {get; set;}

    public CArea(Contact sContact)
    {
        strAreaName = sContact.City;
        liContacts = new list<Contact>{sContact};
    }
}

public list<CArea> liAreas {get; set;}
private map<string, CArea> mapAreas = new map<string, CArea>();

// **snip**
// fill up the list: (assuming contacts)

for(Contact sContact : myContactList}
{
    if(mapAreas.get(sContact.City) == null)
    {
        mapAreas.put(sContact.City, new CArea(sContact));
        liAreas.add(mapAreas.get(sContact.City);
    }
    else
    {
        mapAreas.get(sContact.City).liContacts.add(sContact);
    }
}
```

Now `liAreas` has a list of `CArea` objects, with each one containing a list of contacts, so you can loop over this list in your page:

```
<apex:repeat var="a" value="{!liAreas}">
    <apex:outputText value="{!a.strName}"/>
    <apex:repeat var="c" value="{!a.liContacts}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.FirstName c.LastName}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Option #2:**

This is potentially a lot simpler, but I've not tried dynamic bindings with two levels like this. Similar setup to before, but use a map of areas to list of contacts:

```
public map<string, list<Contact>> mapAreaToContacts {get; set;}
```

Filling this should be easy enough, very similar to the above code. Now use dynamic Visualforce bindings as described in the [Visualforce Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf), in the section **Supporting Maps and Lists**.

Good luck!

Comment: Option 1 did work for me... What if i were to allow updation of the values of name or make?

Comment: If i were to use inputfield in the VF page, which list should i update?

Comment: Hi Prady, if you use apex:inputFields for the contact fields then you should have no problem updating them. In the controller if you updated a contact in one place you'd see the updated version in the other (as you have references to the objects), not sure if this pertains through VF or not. Just realised, you could also remove the list of CAreas in the code and then use the dynamic binding for the map constructed. Might simplify things.

Comment: What i did was to loop through all the CAreas and added contact in a new list and updated the list. It worked fine, maybe not the best way to do it, Will try out the dynamic binding too.. Thanks for your help