# How to merge data from two lists in Apex or VisualForce (Salesforce)?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

What is the best way to merge the two Lists below in Apex or VisualForce? The data is related, but cannot be queried together, so I need to combine the two Lists.

Things to note:

1. The two lists: the additionalInfoQuestionMaps is the parent List and the additionalInfoQuestionAvailableResponses is the child. There can be 1 to many children.
2. I need to join the Lists on the Question_Type_Info__c object.

Basically its a set of Questions coming from the Parent List, then I need to associate possible answers to those questions such as Yes and Nothat reside in the Child List. Those results will be displayed on a VF page in a form.

```
public with sharing class mytest {

    public List<Questions__c> additionalInfoQuestionMaps {get;set;}
    public List<Available_Question_Answer_Options__c> additionalInfoQuestionAvailableResponses {get;set;} 
    public List<retrieveMergedQuestionList> retrieveMergedQuestionLists {get;set;}

    public String buildId {get;set;}

    public Build__c build {get;set;}

    public mytest() {

        buildId = 'a1DV00000001BBBBBB';
        build = sharedfile.getBuild(buildId);
        updateAdditionalInfoQuestionMaps();
        updateAdditionalInfoFieldValueIds();
        updateAdditionalInfoQuestionAvailableResponses();
    }

    public void updateAdditionalInfoQuestionMaps() {

            additionalInfoQuestionMaps = new List<Questions__c>([SELECT Id, Name, 
                          Associated_Product_Item__c, 
                          Associated_Product__c, 
                          Label__c,
                             (select Response__c from Responses_Object__r),  
                          Question_Type_Info__c,  
                          Required__c
                    FROM Questions__c                
                    WHERE Associated_Product__c = :build.Associated_Product__c 
                    ORDER BY Sort_Index__c, Label__c]);
    }

    public Set<Id> additionalInfoFieldValueIds = new Set<Id>();

    public void updateAdditionalInfoFieldValueIds(){
        for (Questions__c aimb : additionalInfoQuestionMaps) {
                additionalInfoFieldValueIds.add(aimb.Question_Type_Info__c);
        }
    }

    public void updateAdditionalInfoQuestionAvailableResponses() {
            additionalInfoQuestionAvailableResponses = new List<Available_Question_Answer_Options__c>([select Id,
                        Field_Value__c, Question_Type_Info__c
                        from Available_Question_Answer_Options__c
                        where Question_Type_Info__c IN :additionalInfoFieldValueIds]);

    }           

}
```

Comment: Your question is hard for me to follow. Can you specify exactly which two lists(please give exact variable names) you would like merged into a single list?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should go in for a wrapper class if i understood your question correctly

Take look at a similar question i had posted earlier where LaceySnr had given the solution

[how to create sections of grouped data in Vf page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900129/how-to-create-sections-of-grouped-data-in-vf-page)

Hope this helps.

Thanks